# How to automatically mount a drive?

Tags: mount, fstab

I just successfully mounted my NAS drive to my raspberry pi 3. I then attempted to add it to the fstab to have it mount automatically when the device is rebooted.

When I went to test it, as it was rebooting it would enter emergency mode and I could not get out of it. I since have reinstalled rasbian, and am going through the process of mounting my NAS again.

My question is, how do I go about automatically mounting my NAS. I had it working for my USB External hard drive, but it obviously did not work for the NAS.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
roc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
dev/mmcblk0p6  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p7  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

Above is my current fstab.

Comment: Try posting what you put in fstab, without that, one can only speculate what the problem is.

Comment: @medbot added it above. thanks for the suggestion. I currently do not have anything attempting to auto mount it because I did not wish to screw it up again.

Comment: How do you currently mount the network drive? Can you show the mount command? There's a more-proper way to do this with `fstab`. From looking at your `fstab` above, it doesn't look like your NAS drive is actually contained in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `_netdev` option on `/etc/fstab`. This tells raspbian that the mountpoint in question is a network device and will defer mounting until the network is up. `man mount` gives you more information on that.

Answer (score 0):

I use a crontab entry to mount a networked drive when I'm fairly sure it is ready.

In my ordinary user crontab I have the following entry

`@reboot (sleep 30; /bin/mount /mount_point) &`

where `mount_point` is the mount point declared in `/etc/fstab`.